# Creating and migrating a devise-driven User model in a main/replica context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, distributed-database

The following main/replica database structure

```
development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: users_development
    username: deploy_root
    password: password
    host: "localhost"
    migrations_paths: db/user_migrate
  primary_replica:
    <<: *default
    database: users_development
    username: deploy_readonly
    password: password
    host: "localhost"
    replica: true
```

has defined as its main AR defined as:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  connects_to database: { writing: :primary, reading: :primary_replica }
end
```

However, when The following commands are run [following the suggested syntax by the rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#generators-and-migrations)

```
rails generate devise User nick avatar --database users
bin/rails db:migrate
```

the only response is a prompt. Two problems arise:

1. the migration is created but not in the proper directory `migrations_paths: db/user_migrate`
2. Logging into the database `users_development=# \dt` returns, consistently with the prompt reply `Did not find any relations.` In other words the table was not created (which is confirmed by the `schema.rb` file being unaltered

is specifying `migrations_paths` with a sub directory a mistake for the primary database connection?
Or should `rails generate devise User nick avatar --database users` invoke `primary` in lieu of `users`?

Comment: primary should not have `migrations_paths`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary database is assumed to have its migrations in the `migrate` directory, not a sub-directory.

```
development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: users_development
    username: deploy_root
    password: password
    host: "localhost"
  primary_replica:
    <<: *default
    database: users_development
    username: deploy_readonly
    password: password
    host: "localhost"
    replica: true
```

Running a `rails generate` with `--database name_of_primary_database` will proceed as in single database application.

Although, this observer would have enjoyed that all migrations be organised in a similar manner, `migrations_paths` is not allowed for a primary database.